# Price Book Access Control?

Tags: administration, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook

Is anyone aware of a way to **control access to Price Books**?  I'm finding no joy either here on SE or via Google.

Our company previously had price books for each "country region" (like *North America, Latin America*, etc), and scrapped that long ago.  Now they'd like to have price books that are for the Front End sales (of the primary product) and back end sales (of the follow-up products) and probably more later.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pricebook visibility is controlled through the sharing model.  Create each price book and then click the share button on it and select the appropriate groups who can use it.

One caveat for developers, SOQL queries for price books do NOT respect sharing rules as you'd expect and will always return all price books in the results.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  The sharing model still in place (I've been here almost 3 years) still mostly predates me minus a couple changes.  It's something I need to revisit relatively soon.